# How can I get the first key from JSON in javascript / NODE.js?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON:

```
{ "%7B%22userName%22%3A%22JAK%22%7D": "" }
```

How can I retrieve the first key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var key = Object.keys({ '%7B%22userName%22%3A%22JAK%22%7D': '' })[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON is stored in variable `data`:

```
Object.keys( data ).shift()
```

Another approach might be this:

```
var name; for ( name in data ) { if ( data.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) break; }
```

This second approach isn't creating separate array just to get its first element.